# Spark, Scala and eval of string transformation expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Spark DataFrame transformation logic:

```
val newCols = df.schema.map {
    dfColumn =>

        val colName = dfColumn.name
        val column = col(colName)

        colName match {
        case "country" => when(column === "Italy", "[ITALY]")
            .when(column === "France", "*France*")
            .otherwise(column).as("[COUNTRY]")
        case "email" => column.as("(EMAIL)")
        case _       => column
    }
}
```

According to the application logic I need to be able to define the transformation logic for each column, like for example:

```
 when(column === "Italy", "[ITALY]")
.when(column === "France", "*France*")
.otherwise(column)
```

outside of the Spark application, for example on the application UI(write it as plain text in HTML TextArea) and then pass this transformation expression as a String to the Spark application and evaluate it there.

Is it possible with Scala and Spark and if so, could you please show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run queries on Dataframes using the alternative API below:

Register dataframe as temp table

```
df.registerTempTable("myTable")
```

Then run a query on it:

```
spark.sql("select a as b from myTable")
```

So you could obtain your expressions for each column your are selecting as strings from wherever, build your SQL query and run as above...

You could build a query something like this...

```
def buildQuery(columns: Seq[String], table: String): String {
   columns.mkString("select ", ", ", s" from $table")
}

val columns = Seq(
   """a as b""",
   """<some more complex case statement>""",
   // etc.
)

def buildQuery(columns: Seq[String], table: String): String {
   columns.mkString("select ", ", ", s" from $table")
}

df.sql(buildQuery(columns, "myTable"))
```